# D3 - Update bar chart per 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a D3 bar chart, with some data drawn initially. I will be getting new data per 2 seconds. This new data could be new items or new counts for existing items. I want to update the chart accordingly.

This is what I have tried:

https://jsfiddle.net/rutwick/an1d95h1/2/

```
var sales = [
    { product: 'Hoodie',  count: 7 },
    { product: 'Jacket',  count: 6 },
    { product: 'Snuggie', count: 9 },
    { product: 'Beanie', count: 8 }
];
var startTimer = false;

function drawGraph() {

    //select the svg
    var svg = d3.select('svg');

    //Select all the rect elements and assign the data to them
    var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(sales);

    //This will access the rect element for creating new rect elements
    var newRects = rects.enter();

    // recall that scales are functions that map from
    // data space to screen space
    // Max limit for Y axis
    var maxCount = d3.max(sales, function(d, i) {
        return d.count;
    });

    //X axis will have bars, hence ordinal scale used
    //domain - data - Product values
    //Rangebound specifies max limit and the padding around the bands
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(sales.map(function(d) {
        return d.product;
    }))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, 500], 0.10); //300 = Total width of all bars, 0.10 = Factor of space between the bars

    //Y axis is linear, hence linear scale used
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([400, 0])
        .domain([0, maxCount]);

    newRects.append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x(d.product);
        })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return y(d.count);
    })
    .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
    .attr('height', function(d, i) {
      return 400 - y(d.count);
    });

    startTimer = true;
    rects.exit().remove();
}

function updateGraph(){
    if(!startTimer) {
        return;
    }
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * sales.length);
    /*if(sales[rand].count % 2 === 0) {
    sales[rand].count += 2;
        console.log(sales[rand].count);
    }*/
    sales.push({ product: 'Denim', count: 1 });
    sales.push({ product: 'Sweatshirt', count: 12 });
    drawGraph();
}
setInterval(updateGraph, 2000);
drawGraph();
```

It updates, but doesn't redraw the chart. Just adds the new bars over the old ones. My current plan includes removing all the rect elements using jQuery, but I don't know if it will work.

What exactly needs to be done to update the complete chart, both on x and y axes?

Comment: you are updating the data but like you said you are just adding to the chart. You need to remove the original data and then add the new. I would create a variable, populate it with the old data, run through the data check if any of the data matches, remove matching data then add new data and redraw the graph :)

Comment: Thanks! You mean update the object? I am adding just 2 values to the object for testing. Please can you modify the fiddle accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

First you need to define the object like this:

```
var rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(sales, function(d){/*Unique ID of a record*/ return d.product;});
```

Now create rectangle like this:

```
  newRects.append('rect');
```

Now update all the rect with new width and height.

```
  //do update
  d3.selectAll("rect")
  .attr('class', "rects")
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    console.log(d)
    return x(d.product);
    })
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return y(d.count);
  })
  .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
  .attr('height', function(d, i) {
    return 400 - y(d.count);
  });
```

Finally remove bars for which data has been removed:

```
  //remove not there
    rects.exit().remove()
```

The problem why your code was not updating:

When you do this the attribute update only on create

```
newRects.append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d) {
            return x(d.product);
        })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return y(d.count);
    })
    .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
    .attr('height', function(d, i) {
      return 400 - y(d.count);
    });
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/drzfaxqa/3/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! So I had to select the `rect` elements again using `d3` and add an `exit` > `remove` sequence?

Comment: yes! the remove will work only when you remove a product when you call the update function. This blog will definitely help you https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36#.2fgr4guob

Comment: Thanks! :) I will go through the blog post. How would I manage adding new records, meaning new bars?

Comment: You don't have to write a single line the current code will manage that just change the data  with new product it will automatically come.

Comment: Let me try that! Another quick question, when you create the `rect`, you're mapping only the `product` field, and not the entire sales object, like I was doing earlier. Where does that affect?

Comment: No i am not mapping anything .. i am saying that the function returns the unique id to define the data `function(d){/*Unique ID of a record*/ return d.product;}` .. entire sales object will be there else this line would have errored `.attr('height', function(d, i) {
      return 400 - y(d.count);
    })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval() function to call particular function for a given period. So you just written an update function to update graph and set it as an argument of setInterval function.

For Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var dps1 = []; // dataPoints
var dps2 = []; // dataPoints
var dps3 = []; // dataPoints
var dps4= []; // dataPoints

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title :{
        text: "Dynamic Data"
    },
    axisY: {
        includeZero: false
    },      
    data: [{
        type: "spline",
        dataPoints: dps1
    },{
        type: "spline",
        dataPoints: dps2
    },{
        type: "spline",
        dataPoints: dps3
    },{
        type: "spline",
        dataPoints: dps4
    }
    ]
});

var xVal = 0;
var yVal = 100; 
var updateInterval = 1000;
var dataLength = 20; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

var updateChart = function (count) {

    count = count || 1;

    for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
        dps1.push({
            x: xVal,
            y: yVal
        });
        yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
        dps2.push({
            x: xVal,
            y: yVal
        });
        yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
        dps3.push({
            x: xVal,
            y: yVal
        });
        yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
        dps4.push({
            x: xVal,
            y: yVal
        });

        xVal++;
    }

    if (dps1.length > dataLength) {
        dps1.shift();
    }
    if (dps2.length > dataLength) {
        dps2.shift();
    }
    if (dps3.length > dataLength) {
        dps3.shift();
    }
    if (dps4.length > dataLength) {
        dps4.shift();
    }

    chart.render();
};

updateChart(dataLength);
setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; max-width: 920px; margin: 0px auto;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I update my chart in every one seconds.